# How to prove this inequality related to subsets of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty sets of real numbers such that $A \subset B$. Prove that:
$$
\min B \leq \min A \leq \max A \leq \max B
$$

Comment: Any thoughts? Tried anything?

Comment: I've tried starting out with the definition of a subset and incorporating the definition of min and max, but I'm stuck on how to actually prove it

Comment: I have edited your post (shortened the title; introduced latex; removed some tags). Please let me know if anything is wrong with that.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $b_0=\min B$ and $a_0=\min A$. Then $a_0\in A\subset B\Rightarrow a_0\in B$. But since $b_0$ is the minimum of $B$, we have $b_0\leq a_0$.

This proves that $\min B\leq \min A$. Also, $\min A\leq\max A$ is trivial. It remains to show that $\max A\leq \max B$.

Put $a_m=\max A$ and $b_m=\max B$. Then $a_m\in A\subset B\Rightarrow a_m\in B$. But since $b_m$ is the maximum of $B$, you have $a_m\leq b_m$. Done.

**Note:** These inequalities hold for *closed* sets of real numbers. If they're not closed they might not have a minimum or a maximum. In this case, the same inequality holds for infima and suprema of $A$ and $B$, but the proof for this is different, because infimum or supremum of a set does not necessarily belong to the set, while the minimum and maximum (if they exist), they belong by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality in the middle is trivial. I will do for you the first one. Pick a point $a \in A$. Then, $a \in B$. Therefore, $\min B \leq a $. In particular,  $\min B$ is a lower bound for the set $A$. Hence $\min B \leq \inf A$. But, by definition $\inf A \leq \min A $. Hence, $\min B \leq \min A $. The last inequality is similar.